# python chatroom with sockets not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm creating a chatroom program with sockets and threads where one client is intended to send a message to the server. The server is then suppose to send that message back to every client.

The problem seems to be in server.py where reciever() doesn't seem to be recieving any messages when the client sends the message.

I've tried debugging and it seems that if i remove the while loop in the listening() function, reciever() works again however then listening() is broken. Any ideas?

server.py

```
    import socket, sys, os
    from threading import Thread

    listOfUsers = []

    IP = '192.168.1.128'

    listeningPort = 5000
    recievingPort = 5001
    sendingPort = 5002

    listeningSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    recievingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sendingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    listeningSocket.bind((IP, listeningPort))
    recievingSocket.bind((IP, recievingPort))

    def listening():
        '''Waits for the a client to send its data( the IP address)
        which is added to listOfUsers'''
        global listOfUsers
        while True:
            print('sdfg')
            data, addr = listeningSocket.recvfrom(4096)
            data = data.decode('utf-8')

            if data not in listOfUsers:
                listOfUsers.append(data)
            else:
                pass


    def reciever():
        '''Waits to recieve incoming messages. Once a message is recieved, this
        function sends the message to every IP address in listOfUsers'''
        while True:
            data, addr = recievingSocket.recvfrom(4096)
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
            with open('E:\\log.txt', 'a') as file:
                file.write(data)
            print(data)
            print(listOfUsers)
            data = data.encode()

            for ip in listOfUsers:
                sendingSocket.sendto(data, (ip, sendingPort))

    def main():
        t1 = Thread(target= listening(), args=())
        t2 = Thread(target= reciever(), args=())


        t1.start()
        t2.start()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('Starting server... \n')
        main()
```

client.py

```
import socket, sys, os, datetime
from threading import Thread


name = os.getlogin()

ServerIP = '192.168.1.128'
hostIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

initialisationPort = 5000
sendingPort = 5001
recievingPort = 5002

initialisationSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sendingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
recievingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

recievingSocket.bind((hostIP, recievingPort))

def initialisation():
    '''Function runs once. Sends this machine's IP address to the server'''
    hostIPCopy = hostIP.encode('utf-8')
    initialisationSocket.sendto(hostIPCopy, (ServerIP, initialisationPort))



def sender():
    '''Waits for input from the user. Once an input is recieved, it creates
    a message to send to the server'''
    while True:
        message = input()
        if message == "end":
            sendingSocket.close()
            recievingSocket.close()
            sys.exit()
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y | %H:%M")
        message = '{0} - {1}: {2}' .format(time, name, message)
        sendingSocket.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), (ServerIP, sendingPort))

def reciever():
    '''Waits for any incoming message from the server'''
    while True:
        data, addr = recievingSocket.recvfrom(4096)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')

        print(data)


def main():
    initialisation()

    t1 = Thread(target=sender, args=())
    t2 = Thread(target=reciever, args =())

    t1.start()
    t2.start()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Enter anything to send to chatroom. Enter "end" to quit.')
    main()
```

Comment: Havent really looked any deep into your code. I see that you use threads here. A word of advice, you will save yourself a lot of headache by just using select functionality instead. You wont notice any "difference"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code.

Your server code fails first in this:

```
def main():
    t1 = Thread(target= listening(), args=())
    t2 = Thread(target= reciever(), args=())
```

Your need to change it and remove parentheses. What happens now is that you call the listening function there when creating t1. Your program stands there waiting in your listening function and never returning. It never even creates the receiver.  Always if you need a function name as parameter, use `function`, not `function()`.

```
def main():
    t1 = Thread(target= listening, args=())
    t2 = Thread(target= reciever, args=())
```

will fix this issue for you.

Your next issue, in both client and server, is that you just start your threads and then your main program exits.  They might hang on a socket timeout, but do not rely on this. Instead, make your main program wait as well:

```
t1 = Thread(target=sender, args=())
t2 = Thread(target=reciever, args =())
t1.daemon = True
t2.daemon = True
t1.start()
t2.start()
while True:
    sleep(60)
```

I have added a dummy sleep. Do this in both client and server. I also suggest adding `daemon = True`. It is not needed but if you interrupt your program, your threads go as well and you do not have a program that hangs and needs to be killed manually.